# Twopart Embedded API Message Discord.py(branch>rewrite)

Tags: api, discord.py, embed

How can I make an API like:
https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/joke/Dark?blacklistFlags=nsfw,religious,political,racist,sexist&type=twopart
look like this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyWQ6.png

Comment: Hi, I am sorry to say this is a very poor question, please be more explicative and verbose, explain in detail the goals, show what you tried and explain the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I used `aiohttp` btw you need to import it. and made the response as `json` after that get the info into the embed.

```py
@bot.command()
async def joke(ctx):
    url = 'https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/joke/Dark?blacklistFlags=nsfw,religious,political,racist,sexist&type=twopart'
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as r:
            if r.status == 200:
                info = await r.json()
                embed = discord.Embed(title=info['setup'], description=info['delivery'])
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: This is probably gonna work, but it's not recommened using requests or urllib, use aiohttp instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use `requests` or `urllib` modules, but they're [blocking](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean) you should use `aiohttp` instead.

```py
import aiohttp

@bot.command()
async def joke_embed(ctx):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession as cs:
        async with cs.get('https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/joke/Dark?blacklistFlags=nsfw,religious,political,racist,sexist&type=twopart') as res:
            resp = await res.json()


    setup, delivery = resp['setup'], resp['delivery']
    embed = discord.Embed(title=setup, description=delivery, colour=discord.Colour.greyple())

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

- [aiohttp docs](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/)